# Can anyone explain me what is happening in this line of typescript code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
const res = JSON.parse(resObj as string)
```

I am new to typescript can anyone please explain what is happening in the above code ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461479/what-is-the-type-assertion-operator-for-in-typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resObj` is being interpreted as type string, and then parsed as a JSON string.

The reason for declaring `as string` is most likely that `resObj` is being returned by an external or async service which does not return a single type of object, but in this instance the user knows the return will be a string (whereas typescript does not).

`JSON.parse` is then converting the string into a usable Javascript object. Eg:

```js
const resObj = `{"prop1":"foo","prop2":3,"prop3":false}`;
const res = JSON.parse(resObj);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

`resObj as string` is a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). It tells typescript "treat resObj as though it's a string, even though the information you have says its not".

Type assertions are occasionally necessary when you know something that typescript does not. But you're basically telling typescript to not check your work, so if you use it when resObject actually isn't a string, then typescript cannot point this out to you, and you may get an exception or other unexpected behavior at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse has some good docs on this.

Let's assume `resObj` is some json blob like `'{"result":true, "count":42}'`

First of all

```
resObj as string
```

means that we are typecasting whatever `resObj` is to a string. This is just  to make sure we're working with the right types, when we call that `JSON.parse` function.

```
const res = JSON.parse(resObj as string)
```

is then doing the following:

1. Casting `resObj` as a string
2. Feeding this string casted `resObj` variable into `JSON.parse`, which will return an `Object { result: true, count: 42 }`
3. Assign `res` to be equal to that `Object { result: true, count: 42 }`

And that's it. You should now be able to access fields on our `res` object, like `res.result` or `res.count`