# What does the TypeScript asserts operator do?

Tags: typescript, assert

I have been toying around with TypeScript in the Node.js RTE, and I ran into a couple of type-operators (or at-least that's what I assume they are), and I don't know anything about them.

The first operator was the `is` operator, which I was able to infer the purpose of, and I found documentation on, the second however; was the assertion operator. I thought at first I understood what its purpose was, but it was behaving in the way I had expected it to, I also failed to promptly find any thorough documentation on the subject, though I am certain it exists, as TS is well documented (especially if you consider what it is that the TS developers have to document).

#### Where I see the Asserts Operator Being Used

I have included a snippet, and a type, that include the `asserts` operator. The two examples below outline situations where I ran into the `asserts` operator, and didn't fully understand the code, because I failed to fully understand what the `asserts` operator does.

---

###### *Below is a code-snippet pulled from a guide on writing unit tests with TypeScript.*

```
function assertNonNullish<TValue>(
  value: TValue,
  message: string
): asserts value is NonNullable<TValue> {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    throw Error(message);
  }
}
```

###### *[Examples Source](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/assertion-functions-in-typescript#implementing-an-assertion-function)*

---

I also find the assert operator used to define the types of most assertion functions that included in the Node.js assertion library. This is what my hover widget shows for the assertions function `deepStrictEqual`'s type:
[image]

###### _...and this is the code for the assertion function's type (same as the image, just in code form):

```
type DeepStrictEqual = <T>(actual: unknown, expected: T, message?: string | Error | undefined) => asserts actual is T;
```

I really don't understand the purpose of using the assertion operator. I would like to figure out how it relates to typing JavaScript code, and writing unit-tests & assertion functions in TypeScript, so I can better understand when (and where) I should use it.

Comment: I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461479/what-is-the-type-assertion-operator-for-in-typescript about an assertion operator. It is references the `as` operator as the "Assertion Operator", is as the same thing as the asserts operator? I am really confused TBH.

Comment: First link that showed up when I searched for "typescript asserts"; https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/assertion-functions Has a pretty good explanation in the comments, and a link to the release notes for when it was released. I'm sure with a modicum of searching in TypeScript's GitHub repo, you could find the issue that proposed it.

Comment: assertions in most languages are useful when writing tests.

Comment: Found this link to be very helpful: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/#assertion-functions

Answer (score 13):

[Assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) are used when you need to narrow a value to more a specific type, and you need a strong guarantee that the type meets your expectation before running other code.

Consider the following example, where you begin with a variable that might be a `string` or a `number`, and you need to use that value with a function that only accepts a `number`:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEziARgGwKaIBRgBciYIAtutgE4CUxpF1iA3gLABQiiV2UIVSJACpEAJgDcHAL4cOoSLASIAhgGdV1KAElVAOXKUq+AG7LMIbMXABrMHADuYOivWbViU+dwx3DQyw4uGGB8KABPAAdsOBDPC0QAQgBeJMQAcj9qNJpEKAALKgcSbHtEAFEqQqo8NN04KBUSAyyaSXYZdjlwaHgkbAAPZTIInBMzC2JVKCoYMABzRAAfJsZaYmM4GGQAzlyqMJ2uLjUNKm09Zuq47FbAo4gEVTgcADpMODm8VAwcPGuaW67DpcCDKKAQPL4AYQbARRROQ73R7PbAvahVPDQ2HwwFcDodDgDIYjbA1PLYTDvbLiRAAelp5UqcCoxDqDWUK0MhMGw1+AEY+a06QzRKIOEA)

```ts
function double (n: number): number {
  return n * 2;
}

function assertIsNumber (value: unknown): asserts value is number {
  if (typeof value !== 'number') throw new Error('Not a number');
}

function example (value: string | number): void {
  try {
    assertIsNumber(value);
    console.log(double(value));
  }
  catch (exception) {
    console.error(exception);
  }
}

example('hello'); // Error: Not a number
example(11); // 22
```

If you don't assert the type to be a `number`, you cannot use it with the `double` function:

```ts
function example (value: string | number): void {
  try {
    console.log(double(value)); /*
                       ~~~~~
    Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345) */
  }
  catch (exception) {
    console.error(exception);
  }
}
```

The assertion function allows you to use the value for the remainder of the scope, narrowed to be the type that you asserted it to be.

If you had only used a [predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), then you would need to move your code into a new block (inside the matching conditional) every time you wanted to use the value as the narrowed type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEziARgGwKaIBRgBciYIAtutgE4CUxpF1iA3gLABQiiV2UIVSJACpEAJgDcHAL4cOoSLASIYAZwBy5SlXwA3AIaYQ2YuADWYOAHcwdRPsO5VJTUzaduvfkigBPAA7YcMB2BkaIALyRiADkDFrRkuwy7HLg0PBI2AAeemR+OLqhxogqUFQwYADmiAA+zoy0xDpwMMgsHFwwwXiqGg149kY0NO3uXBAIKnA4AHSYcJV4qBg4A0XDiVzJXNiYKrhuXFwA9MeIMxcdiMnJQA)

```ts
function double (n: number): number {
  return n * 2;
}

function isNumber (value: unknown): value is number {
  return typeof value === 'number';
}

function example (value: string | number): void {
  if (isNumber(value)) {
    console.log(double(value));
  }
  else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

---

P.S. I find that it can be more flexible to use a generic assertion function and compose it with type predicates like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEziARgGwKaIBRgBciYIAtutgE4CUxpF1iA3gLABQiiV2UIVSJACpEAJgDcHAL4cOoSLASIAhgGdV1KPmwAPAA5Vi4ANZg4AdzAAaRGVUBzAPzFVUKjDD26K9ZtWJdAxYOLhhgfABCQNpEKAALKgsSbHNEAFEqRKo8Oy9Jdhl2OXBoeCQYVQA5ckoqfAA3ZUwQbCMwUwswb0bm3AqSGqY2Tm5efiQoAE89bDhwnpbEAF4VxAByBlq1-MLihTKAnWUyPRwGppaXNw97RAAfAcZaYnq4GGRgkbUNKig8CuqTzwC2wNBsa0qcC0ykeWxo+S4EAQqjgOAAdJg4PY8KgMDhgRdQfDpBwgA)

```ts
function double (n: number): number {
  return n * 2;
}

function assert (expr: unknown, msg?: string): asserts expr {
  if (!expr) throw new Error(msg);
}

function isNumber (value: unknown): value is number {
  return typeof value === 'number';
}

function example (value: string | number): void {
  assert(isNumber(value), 'Not a number');
  console.log(double(value));
}
```

For more examples of assertion functions, see this Deno standard module: [`https://deno.land/std@0.132.0/testing/asserts.ts`](https://deno.land/std@0.132.0/testing/asserts.ts) ([documentation](https://doc.deno.land/https://deno.land/std@0.132.0/testing/asserts.ts)). (I [contributed the assertion typing](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/pull/969) for the one called [`assertExists`](https://doc.deno.land/https://deno.land/std@0.132.0/testing/asserts.ts/%7E/assertExists), which is like the function in your example.)