# Modelling an assembly line in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a script that works a bit like an assembly line. It starts with a dictionary with an object with only one property and adds one more property after each step.

I started with plain JS and am now converting this to TS.

I have modeled this now as a Typescript interface with one mandatory property and a lot of optional properties:

```
interface CarBatch {
  [key: string]: {
    part1: string;
    part2?: string[];
    part3?: SteeringWheel;
    part4?: string;
    part5?: string;
    part6?: string;
  }
}
```

However, Typescript complains a lot about this, as accessing these optional properties always yields "Object is possibly 'undefined'". For example `console.log(carBatch['porsche'].part4)`

I tried to use a base interface and `extends` but this was difficult because of the dictionary and because my assembly steps always would start with one kind of type and would need to modify pieces of it to another type in the middle.

What would be the correct way to model this?

Comment: why don't you use question mark for handing it 
like this : console.log(carBatch?.['porsche']?.part4)

Comment: Check out [user-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) and [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) in the TS handbook. I also wrote an answer explaining their usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71625025/438273).

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75371169/modelling-an-assembly-line-in-typescript#comment132993532_75371169) Those concepts can be used to inform the compiler of runtime mutations like you described in your question. However, without a [mre], it's hard to know what exactly you're struggling with. Can you update the question to include one (and also provide a link to it in the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/Q))?

Answer (score 0):

As per Ali's comment, this could be handled by adding question marks to the console.log:

`console.log(carBatch?.['porsche']?.part4)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to loosely follow the builder pattern. As such, you may type it like this:

```
function addStage<P extends Record<string, unknown>, K extends string, V>(
  previous: P, key: K, value: V
): P & { [key in K]: V } {
  return {
    ...previous,
    [key]: value,
  };
}

// Usage
const stage1 = addStage({}, 'part1', 1);
//    ^?
const stage2 = addStage(stage1, 'part2', 'value');
//    ^?
const stage3 = addStage(stage2, 'part3', [1, 2, 3]);
//    ^?
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoMpWQcwKYA8ACongB5R5ioDOiASnhHAE6oE1Qsxg4A0icAGswcAO5gAfAIDSpClVqJO3XgIBqkgBQAHFngBu8EDQBciIgKF4AnuZkCDyADYg859QEpzJAGSIAb0QAbWsbRB5EGQBdD0QAX0CAKEREfSgQFiQAlNTEADpCvUNjGj5c1NDbWMQnVzxy1PiAbiT4pKTmME5lbHwARkQAXhR0LFw8LQD4gQByHWQWKH7ZgX7PVoB6TbzEAD0Afk6EHs4JgCZh0cw%20ybOBuYWl89XEWbq3WY2k7d3D4%206UF6EwAzFc0DcJlp7nhzo9FlAQa9gv0BHDECDot9fnlDkA)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the built-in utility type `Pick` to good use.

Let's declare a completed `Car` as a separate interface first:

```
interface Car {
  part1: string;
  part2: string[];
}
```

I'm omitting `part3` through `part6` to keep things short, but rest assured that this approach scales well.

An unfinished car is represented as the type `PartialCar`, with a generic argument `K` that defines which keys must already be present:

```
type PartialCar<K extends keyof Car> = Pick<Car, K>;
```

Since `CarBatch` might contain unfinished cars, we make it generic:

```
interface CarBatch<C> {
  [key: string]: C
}
```

Note that there's no need to restrict the type `C`.

Let's see how we could create a new batch of cars that only have `part1` assigned:

```
function startBatch(): CarBatch<PartialCar<'part1'>> {
  return {
    'porsche': {
      part1: 'one'
    }
  }
}
```

To add a new part `part2` to all cars, we accept any unfinished car type `C`, and return a batch that contains more finished car type `C & PartialCar<'part2'>`:

```
function addPart2<C>(batch: CarBatch<C>): CarBatch<C & PartialCar<'part2'>> {
  const outputBatch: CarBatch<C & Pick<Car, 'part2'>> = {};
  for (const key of Object.keys(batch)) {
    outputBatch[key] = {
      ...batch[key],
      part2: ['left', 'right'],
    };
  }
  return outputBatch;
}
```

This function works regardless of type `C`, but you can easily restrict it. For example, use `C extends PartialCar<'part1'>` if the assignment of `part2` depends on `part1` being present.

A batch of finished cars is of course a `CarBatch<Car>`:

```
function printBatch(batch: CarBatch<Car>) {
  console.log(batch);
}
```

To show that it all works:

```
let batch = startBatch();
let finishedBatch = addPart2(batch);
printBatch(finishedBatch);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGcgBwzAEYAuZAZzClAHMBuPQ4gJgutpDoG0BdJgF8cOMAE8CKAArFgcADbooAHgDSyCAA9IIACaVkAawhiA9jDQYAfMgC8yKcASHlSgDTJVVpjlCRYiChKAEJwYAgAFq42uPg8xmIcNPR8FKg4wjgwAK4gCGDApiBUYMSh4REAFACUaRjlkcoyUAUKSsoA5EQtJB1WMcxQEGDZUMWx+MhdplCUkRAdFBOTLD0UHUULzPjCOxkiOXkFRchwurrNYKyuGtoQegaXcooYnd2kfVaVAEZhkXVQBpRVBWWqWQF-YHIABkDlkbVeXTYn2wzAQRWoyFM2TABBxQIBQJusMczlcGA8SJarBR9iwgiY+BgM2QlXRIExCSxFgA8t8AFYQfIAOgSlB+kOq1VRK2xuPxkPiJj4dhlK2Qws1vwqSrEfDc20m73YyB4HXkEBgYA6lNodAi1v1hoZzF2yCGIzGWJxeLAQKEB1y+UKxQIXD9kIlFUJkPJUFBavZlFMFuF8lMdCjkWqAZwFrAyG1kVV1DKkZzeeGyBgoGAlAiEF0QNVZwubCzEQrYb8QMqNZAdYbTclDCAA)