# Understanding the mechanics of the "as" keyword in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

If I understand correctly, the "as" keyword specifies the exact type of a disjunction of types. Take a look at the following commented example:

```js
type Fish = { swim: () => void };
type Bird = { fly: () => void };

function getSmallPet(): Fish | Bird {
  let bird: Bird = {fly: () => {
    console.log("airrrr")
  }}
  let fish: Fish = {swim: () => {
    console.log("whoosh")
  }}

  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? fish : bird 
}
// ---cut---
let pet = getSmallPet();
let fishPet = pet as Fish; // if pet ends up being a fish, then it should return an object with swim right?
let birdPet = pet as Bird; // if pet ends up being a bird, then it should return an object with fly right?

console.log("fish is")
console.log(fishPet) 
console.log("bird is")
console.log(birdPet)

// both pets above are empty objects. Why?
if (fishPet.swim) {
  fishPet.swim();
} else if (birdPet.fly) {
  birdPet.fly();
}
// however, we still successfuly call one of the above methods and either "airrr" or "whoosh" is logged. How is that possible if we found out that both objects are empty?
```

As mentioned in the comments above, both `fishPet` and `birdPet` are empty objects? Why? If we ended up with a bird, shouldn't the `as Fish` keyword provide us either an empty object or undefined and the `as Bird` provide us with an object with a method that logs "airrr"? And vice versa when we end up with a fish? Why is the `as` keyword acting like this?

Comment: `as` has absolutely no impact at run-time. It's only a compile-time way to communicate that you as a programmer are sure this value is the type you specified. That's it. It's just making the compiler disregard its knowledge of types and accept what you said. It doesn't "cast", nor "verify" nor change the actual value in any way. If you were wrong, then you just lied to the compiler and thus to any future type analysis.

Comment: Start here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions

Comment: Also related: [What is the type assertion operator for in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19461479)